# Disable tab key on a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="div1">Some content</div>
   <div id="div2">Some content</div>
</div>
```

I want to "disable" the tab key on div2, I mean the elements of div2 won't receive focus when the tab key is pressed.

Is there any easy way to create this tab key blocker using javascript/jquery?

Comment: This is just my best guess, but input fields has a tabindex attribute.  I'd set it to -1.  See what happens.  This only applies to input fields though.

Comment: Thanks John, it's working with div's, iframes (facebook like), ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@John Strickler is right. The behaviour of the tab key can be changed with the tabindex attribute. It is the order the elements will have the focus.

With `<div id="div1" tabindex="-1">Some content</div>` you should prevent the focus to be on your div.

More info here: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. Exactly what I came here to post. :)

Comment: I...never considered that... =/ +1 for keeping it simple... :)

Comment: It does not work, which I tested right on this answer. If you focus the comment text field and press `TAB`, focus switches to `Add comment` button. Now, if you execute "Inspect" on the button and add a `tabindex="-1"` to the `<div>` that surrounds the button, and then repeat the experiment, the button still gets focused.

Comment: This won't work if you have an input inside the div: https://codepen.io/thdoan/full/mdzGdQj

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly simple way of doing this, using jQuery's `focus()` method. Given the following, simplified, html:

```
<div id="first">
    <label for="first">Can tab to this input</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" />
</div>
<div id="second">
    <label for="second">Can't tab to this input</label>
    <input type="text" id="second" />
</div>
<div id="third">
    <label for="third">Can tab to this input</label>
    <input type="text" id="third" />
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#second input').focus(
    function(){
        $('#third input:first').focus();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nC6Wd/).

This is, slightly, over-simplified though. If you post your exact mark-up we might be able to offer something a little more...tailored?

It also, in the above implementation, prevents the `input` being focused via the click event, as well as the <kbd>tab</kbd>, which reduces the usefulness, I'd imagine.

---

**Edited** to revise the above code, to differentiate between focus from mouse-click and keyboard-tab:

```
$('#second input').bind('keyup mouseup',
                        function(e){
                            if (e.which == 9) {
                                // focus from tab
                                $('#third input:visible:first').focus();
                            }
                            else if (e.which == 1) {
                                // focus from click
                                return false;
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('God only knows, what buttons are you mashing..?');
                            }
                        });
```

[Revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nC6Wd/1/).

Comment: Thank you for your help, David. However, I think Jason's answer is easier :)

Comment: It certainly is, hence my +1 to his answer =)