# prevent default action for tab key in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to PREVENT the default action when the tab key is pressed and only wanna do it in chrome, i can't find a solution for that, can anyone please help ?

i am using jquery

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's an article on how to detect chrome:
`http://javascriptly.com/2008/09/javascript-to-detect-google-chrome/`

And this question: [Disable tab key on a specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556420/disable-tab-key-on-a-specific-div) might help you on disabling the tab key. If you are able to combine both yourself, you've probably got it working.

The disable function would become something like:

```
$('.textarea').on('keyup mouseup', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 9) { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

e.which = 9 is the tab key according to the last link given. If you are able to wrap the browser detection around it yourself, I guess you've got your working example.

Comment: i am doing preventDefault but it just don't work :( i am doing it on a table cell

Comment: do you have an examepl only, not sure what you are trying to do with a table cell? Or what happens with it when pressing tab?

Comment: i am making an editable grid, when user clicks on a table cell and presses tab then the next cell should be highlighted this works fine but chrome also sets the focus on other elements and with each tab chrome moves the focus to next thing, i dont want that to happen

Comment: You might want to look into your Grid javscript, it most likely is to have a function that binds the tab key. If you can get the chrome detection in there and wrap the function-content inside `if(!is_chrome)` then it might solve your problem.

Comment: but preventDefault should work on both browsers right? i am using preventDefault and it isn't doing what it should do

Comment: not sure if preventDefault also works on browsers. A common mistake however is that people write down e.preventDefault; instead of e.preventDefault(); (it's a function).

Comment: i am writing it as a function

Comment: Hmm strange.. you've got an online demo somewhere?

Comment: @Shaheer, just curious if you got your implementation working? the answer is marked correct but it looks like you were still trying to get it to work?

Comment: Modern working answer: 1. You should use .on, not .bind 2. There can't be a comma between event names. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: By the way, the events should be separated by a space, not a comma. http://api.jquery.com/bind

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` and `KeyboardEvent.which` are deprecated properties. Use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Answer (score 75):

```
input.keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

On keyup is too late, you need to call the event on keydown. That worked for me.

Comment: I found this after accepted answer didnt work. Indeed - keyup is too late. Thanx for the tip :)

Comment: That works! Quirky situation this is.  Perfectly sensible solution here.

Comment: If you use `jQuery-ui` you can use `$.ui.keyCode.TAB` instead of magic number `9`

Comment: Yes, the keyup event only happens after the default has already occurred, so preventing it does nothing.

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` and `KeyboardEvent.which` are deprecated properties. Use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late, but combining @EvgueniNaverniouk's answer and @K._'s comment (on @Joshua_Pendo's answer), it is determined that you must use `onkeydown` and the more recent `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`. What `event.key` does is it returns the name of the key instead of the code. For example, the `tab` key will be returned as "Tab" (This is case sensitive). Here is the finished working code:

```
function checkForTab(event) {
    if (event.key == "Tab") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        //whatever stuff if not Tab
    }
}
document.getElementById("element").onkeydown = checkForTab(event);
```

```js
function checkForTab(event) {
 if (event.key == "Tab") {
  event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('element').value += " Also notice this text appears every time you press tab!";
 }
 else {
  //whatever stuff if not Tab
 }
}
document.getElementById('element').onkeydown = checkForTab;
//Trick is to use keydown and use event.key instead of keyCode
```

```html
<textarea id="element" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">Press tab key here, you'll see default action doesn't occur!</textarea>
```

Run the Code Snippet above to see an example of what I mean. You can now use a code like this to replace the default action of Tab with the action that adds spaces to a textarea. Note: the reason I use `.key` instead of `.keyCode` is because `.keyCode` is now deprecated as @K._ mentioned. ***Hope this helps!***

Comment: just a hint: this did better for me than all the answers stated at the time I wrote this. @EvgueniNaverniouk's answer helped, but still didn't work 100%.

Comment: I am getting  console.log(event.key) as undefined for tab key. Can you tell me why ?
 (blur)=" focusK($event)

Comment: I believe `event.key` in your code is undefined because you are using the `blur` event instead of the `onkeydown` event, @ChandreshMishra. The `blur` event only fires after the textbox has lost focus, so preventing the TAB action with it will not work. In addition, the event for the `blur` event does not measure what keys are pressed because it is a focus-based event, not a keyboard-based event. Simply call your `focusK` method like so: `keydown="focusK"` on your textbox. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue. I had wasted 2 days in this :(

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
  document.getElementById('message_textarea').addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    console.log('tab pressed on message textarea');
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="message_textarea"></textarea>
```